# Cannot login using Gnome after upgrade from 16.04 to 17.10

Tags: gnome, xorg, 17.10, gdm

I am getting a login loop after upgrading from 16.04 to 17.10.

- At the login screen, I can enter my password and hit enter. Screen goes black for about 2 seconds and then I am back where I started.

That was using the "Gnome on Xorg" setting.

When I use "Unity" it works OK and lets me in.

I have tried numerous things including re-install of `ubuntu-session` `gdm3`, but I am still having this issue.

lspci
https://pastebin.com/WZdhscpy

Log
https://pastebin.com/NJfjpM9V